# How to display output Halves of previous numbers and in decimal in C#

Tags: c#

How to get the output halve of previous numbers? For example, I put the input 0.2, then I want to display the triangle output;
0.1
0.05
0.0025.....until the break instruction met.

What should I add after Convert. in var? e.g, rows = Convert. ?

Do I need to add to condition inside for loop e.g,
for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++) ?

Comment: Ordinarily it's expected here on StackOverflow that you will demonstrate how far you have progressed. Please can you post a sample of the code you have written so far.

Comment: @bugmagnet I already found the solution as example below;

decimal  num = 1;

for (num = 1; num > 0.001m; num /= 2) 
{
Console.WriteLine(num)
}

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void HalveNum()
{
    decimal num = 1;
    for (num = 1; num = 0.001m; num /=2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
}
```